# Is there a way to override the css style sheet?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing my personal page for a virtual grad show in lieu of COVID, hence the school passed us a format that we could use, and told us for "security reasons" we could not modify the CSS whatsoever, even if we had access to it. The CSS is as follows.

```
.twocols {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 4vw 8vw 0 8vw;
}

.twocols-spl {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 4vw 8vw 0 8vw;
```

If I don't put in an image in the following code, my text auto centers, but I would like to know if its possible to override the margins manually as I strictly cannot modify the CSS.

```
<div class="twocols" id="mir">

        <img class="left" src="./data/800x800.png" alt="">

        <div class="mir_abstract">
            <h2>Subtitle 2</h2>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis suscipit aperiam laborum necessitatibus quae alias recusandae nostrum eum soluta corrupti quidem temporibus ipsa voluptatum nemo optio, libero, eveniet totam. Fugiat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis suscipit aperiam laborum necessitatibus quae alias recusandae nostrum eum soluta corrupti quidem temporibus ipsa voluptatum nemo optio, libero, eveniet totam. Fugiat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis suscipit aperiam laborum necessitatibus quae alias recusandae nostrum eum soluta corrupti quidem temporibus ipsa voluptatum nemo optio, libero, eveniet totam. Fugiat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis suscipit aperiam laborum necessitatibus quae alias recusandae nostrum eum soluta corrupti quidem temporibus ipsa voluptatum nemo optio, libero, eveniet totam. Fugiat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you have the ability to modify the HTML, could you add in another `<style>` tag?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added a style max width, but it couldnt override the default 50% max width. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<div class="abstract" style = "width: = 80%" style = "max-width: 100%" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add style="" to the specific HTML tag you want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily override it.
Just add Another stylesheet on this page after the first one,
Or add a  tag,
Or use th attribute style="" in the html,
Or add a JS script which update the style of the element if there is no img.

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't put in other JS scripts also for the same "security reasons"

Comment: @AltheaC Just for curiosity's sake, I might test the effectiveness of their security measures. Try inserting `<img src onerror="alert('evil')">`. If `evil` gets alerted, their security measures are insufficient, and you can run scripts :)

Answer (score 1):

You can override by in-line Styling CSS and remove important! If you have used it in code.